# How do I test my Firebase Web app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, karma-jasmine

I have a web app using Firebase Web (client Javascript SDK).
How do I test Auth, Realtime Database triggers, including

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`, `firebase.database().ref(...).on` and etc.

I tried to use [mockfirebase](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase) but it is not triggering `onAuthStateChanged`.

Comment: A while ago, I open-sourced an in-memory mock that I've been using for testing my Firebase projects. You might find it useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-nightlight

Comment: @cartant can you share with me an example of `onAuthStateChanged ` ?

Comment: The mock is unit tested and the tests serve as the documentation; the `onAuthStateChanged` tests are [here](https://github.com/cartant/firebase-nightlight/blob/v2.1.0/source/mock-auth-spec.ts#L98-L167).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create two (or multiple if required) firebase projects and use one for testing.

This is also supported by firebase cli using "Deploy Targets". You can deploy to different firebase projects from the single firebase.json config file in your source control.

For more information check this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets